# Питон программа не открывается при запуске с проводника

Tags: python

[image]

Пишу в pycharm программу. Пытаюсь открыть её в проводнике, но она сразу закрывается.
х = input() не помогает

ниже прикреплю код программы

```
import arcade
WIDTH = 800
HEIGHT = 800
TITTLE = "exe"
class Mygame(arcade.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Mygame, self).__init__(WIDTH, HEIGHT, TITTLE, resizable=True)
        arcade.set_background_color(arcade.color.RED)

    def on_draw(self):
        arcade.start_render()


game = Mygame()
arcade.run()
```

Comment: Нет смысла в коде, если в Проводнике не открывается, а информации о Проводнике нет. Какое расширение у файла видно в Проводнике? И что значит "открыть" в данном контексте - текстовым редактором?

Comment: попробуйте запустить ее используя командую строку. там вы сможете увидеть ошибку из-за которой закрывается программа.

Comment: @n1tr0xs, речь же не идет о запуске, а об открытии. Как открыть файл через командную строку?

Comment: @Сергей судя по описанию проблемы "но она сразу закрывается" речь идет о запуске.

Comment: @n1tr0xs, вам, полагаю, виднее, но двойной клик на *.py в Проводнике тоже вызывает эффект открытия с "сразу закрывается". Относительно многих вопросов могу лишь отметить, что масса людей не владееет семантикой и синтаксисом родного языка. Не удивительно, что потом начинаются проблемы с этими же областями языка машинного.

Comment: Запусти скрипт с консоли(командной строки) и посмотри ошибку, так ни чем не помочь.

Answer (score 1):

Проблема в том, что `arcade` - это библиотека, скаченная через pip в виртуальное окружение проекта. Когда вы нажимаете 2 раза на файлик, то windows запускает глобальный python, который не знает библиотеки `arcade`. Для того, чтобы запустить проект нужно в командной строке (cmd) перейти в папку с файлом и запускать его из под виртуального окружения (`venv\Scripts\python.exe file.py` или сначала `venv\Scripts\activate`, а затем `python file.py`)